# Attach to web application debug issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have my web app hosted on my local machine, and I try to debug it. I always use Attach to process to do this. BUT. Sometimes when I reach breakpoint and press F10 debugger just continue to run app as I press F5, so I can't go to next step. And sometimes I reattach to process and it runs ok, but not too long, some time pass it again do such strange things.

Can you explain why does it happens?

Regards, Dmitry.

Comment: Because the web page gets time outs if you stay too long with open it waiting from the web server response. Also you may be inside a thread, the page is continue with timeout and the thread is stop.

Comment: where can I set this time outs for local version? I mean only when I run it from debug mode.

Comment: First of all, did you make too much time when you debug, passing step to step ? Now I do not know what is time out on you. Maybe a thread, maybe a database connection, maybe the web browser, maybe the session, maybe the pool ? Is it the time out after all?

Comment: No some times it breaks immediately when I reach breakpoint and press F10